# Safari cannot upload file w/ unknown mime type (?) (shows "tempImage")

Tags: html, safari

Here's a very weird bug that occurs in Safari 15.3 and 15.4 (macOS) but not in any other browser.

If I have the following element:

```
<input type="file" accept=".json,.cbor">
```

I can select any .cbor file.

[image: Working]

However, if I do:

```
<input type="file" accept=".json,.jpg,.cbor">
```

Safari shows a 'tempImageXXXXX.jpg' name and does not select the actual file.

[image: Broken]

This *only* happens for .cbor files in our test, but I assume it might have something to do with unknown mime types? .wav, .json, .jpeg, .mp4, etc. all have no issues. Also no other browser has any issues with this. Re-ordering the extensions in the element neither.

To replicate: just rename a txt file to .cbor and paste the code above into jsfiddle.

Comment: Just ran into the very same issue. Any news on this?

Comment: @Schafsmann see my comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: Are you sure the input actually accepts the file. Can you share your html input code? Sometimes there are differences in this aspect with Safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this:

```html
<input type="file" accept="application/json,image/jpg,.cbor" />
```

if that did not work fine, try changing `.cbor` with `text/plain`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did indeed work, but broke again when adding `image/png`. This worked though: `application/json,image/*,.cbor` for `.json`, `.png`, `.jpg` and `.cbor` files (although at the disadvantage of allowing other image files too, but OK).

Answer (score 1):

The actual answer is that Webkit (the web engine behind Safari) is converting images when an image mime-type is listed in the `accept` tag of an HTML element. This has been introduced [with the following change in Webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212482) and it is used in their example to transform HEIC images into JPEG on the fly when an image is drag and dropped from the Photos app.

However, at Ocus, we discovered [a bug linked to this change](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=244666). For some mime-types (which I haven't been able to list) the name of the file is changed to `tempImageXXXXX`. The OP's fix worked because they used `image/*` instead of a specific image mime-type in the `accept` field.

So, the real fix is the above bug.
What you can do meanwhile is use:

```
<input type="file" accept="application/json,image/*,.cbor" />
```

You can check for specific image mime-type by plugging into the input's events.